# How to pronounce libvirt

Tags: libvirt

As tile,
From internet, most people speak as [lib virt].
I thought it is [laib virt], because of library + virtualization.

Wiki & FAQ didn't find the answer.
Any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly it is pronounced as:
Lib as "live" with a B instead of v. (live here is from "we live here", **not** from "live telecast")
vrt as "vert" in advert.

You could've watched a video on youtube to hear it.